# Visual studio 2013 - cordova file plugin issue

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, cordova-plugin-file

Hi I'm working on Ionic framework for mobile app development in Visual studio 2013.
In config.xml I could not able to add cordova file plugin, it shows couldn't able to download plugin., so I manually installed the Plugin from Git repository. The version of the plugin added is 4.2.0 and I added the following lines of code for file creation

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory, function (dir) {
                console.log("got main dir", dir);
                dir.getFile("log.txt", { create: true }, function (file) {
                    console.log("got the file", file);
                    logOb = file;
                    writeLog("App started");
                });
            });
```

But when I try to build the solution, it throws me "couldn't install cordova file plugin" and the build fails. So I downgraded the plugin version to 1.3.1, build succeeds, but it throws "cordova.file" as undefined.

Please help me resolve this issue or if you could recommend me a different method to get around this issue, that would be great!

Thanks for the answers

Comment: Could you try migrating to VS2015?

Comment: I tried with VS2015 and it works fine there. But my entire code is developed in VS2013. Is there any workaround for VS2013?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any workaround for VS2013?

As far as I know, Tools for Apache Cordova served only as "Technique Preview" in VS2013. VS2015 is the correct official version that runs TACO. So I strongly recommend you migrating to VS2015.

> But my entire code is developed in VS2013. Is there any workaround for VS2013?

You can follow [Migrate a Cordova project to Visual Studio 2015](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/migrate-to-vs2015/) to migrate your entire project into VS2015.

Comment: Thank you, I'll upgrade the project to VS2015 using that link.